# R na.approx error: need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Tags: r, interpolation

Sample Data

```
1/1/2000    NA  NA  NA  29.71   NA
1/2/2000    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1/3/2000    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1/4/2000    NA  NA  NA  29.25   NA
1/5/2000    NA  NA  NA  30.28   NA
1/6/2000    NA  NA  NA  27.66   NA
1/7/2000    NA  NA  NA  27.22   NA
1/8/2000    NA  NA  NA  27.27   NA
1/9/2000    170 4.1 NA  5.24    NA
1/10/2000   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1/11/2000   NA  NA  NA  27.65   NA
1/12/2000   NA  NA  NA  28.28   100.57
1/13/2000   NA  NA  NA  27.52   NA
```

I'm trying to interpolate a lot of NA values.

I have unique dates (key), but most [other] data columns begin/end with with NULL/NA values (combined_data_z[,a]).  I care to interpolate these [other] columns empty values against date, I'm having this error when attempting

> ```
> Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) :    need at least two
>   non-NA values to interpolate
> ```

```
library(zoo)

#start with 2 because 1st column is date
a=2
for (i in parsedList)
{

dates <- combined_data_z[,1]
test1 <- combined_data_z[,a]
test1_z <- zoo(test1)
test1_z_approx <- na.fill(na.approx(test1_z, x=dates, rule=2, na.rm = FALSE), "extend")
#print(test1_z_approx)

a=a+1

}
```

update: apparently it has something to do with the for loop, when I removed it and tested using print statements and built up from there, I found that it works when not enclosed in brackets (but I need the loop).

```
dates <- combined_data_z[,1]
test1 <- combined_data_z[,4]
test1_z <- zoo(test1)
test1_z_approx <- na.fill(na.approx(test1_z, x=dates, rule=2, na.rm = FALSE), "extend")
print(test1_z_approx)
```

Comment: Can you check that all your columns have at lest 2 non missing values. It looks like there is at least one column in your data set that has 1 or no non-missing values. To check how many non missing values you have in a column you can do sum(!is.na( combines_data_z[,a])) in your loop

Comment: I confirmed.  A copy of my dataset can be found here: http://thistleknot.sytes.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/output_NoNA.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following dataset you provided in comments this works:

```
library(zoo)
combined_data_z <- read.csv(file="http://thistleknot.sytes.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/output_NoNA.csv")


test1_z_approx <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(combined_data_z)-2, nrow = nrow(combined_data_z))
for (i in 3:ncol(combined_data_z))
{

  dates <- combined_data_z[,1]
  test1 <- combined_data_z[,i]
  test1_z <- zoo(test1)
  test1_z_approx[,i-2] <-as.matrix( na.fill(na.approx(test1_z, x=dates, rule=2, na.rm = FALSE), "extend"))[,1]


}
```

If your dataset starts with the "date" column , then the code will look like:

```
head(combined_data_z)
#          date CPIAUCSL UNRATE MEHOINUSA672N INTDSRUSM193N CIVPART
#    1 1/1/2000    169.3      4         58544             5    67.3
#    2 1/2/2000       NA     NA            NA            NA      NA
#    3 1/3/2000       NA     NA            NA            NA      NA
#    4 1/4/2000       NA     NA            NA            NA      NA
#    5 1/5/2000       NA     NA            NA            NA      NA
#    6 1/6/2000       NA     NA            NA            NA      NA

test1_z_approx <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(combined_data_z)-1, nrow = nrow(combined_data_z))
for (i in 2:ncol(combined_data_z))
{

  dates <- combined_data_z[,1]
  test1 <- combined_data_z[,i]
  test1_z <- zoo(test1)
  test1_z_approx[,i-1] <-as.matrix( na.fill(na.approx(test1_z, x=dates, rule=2, na.rm = FALSE), "extend"))[,1]

}

head(test1_z_approx)
#         [,1]     [,2]  [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 169.3000 4.000000 58544 5.000000 67.30000
#[2,] 224.0420 4.033100 59039 2.844406 64.07145
#[3,] 196.4639 3.959895 59039 4.579983 65.57215
#[4,] 188.9426 3.939930 59039 5.053322 65.98144
#[5,] 186.4355 3.933275 59039 5.211101 66.11786
#[6,] 183.9284 3.926620 59039 5.368881 66.25429
```

Comment: when I export to csv, list exports with incorrect headers, includes an additional row column, and no date column.  In reallife, I'm not working with a csv, this csv is an export of a dataframe called df3. I was able to make that change from combined_data_z in my original code. :)

Comment: I really wish I didn't use that .csv.  I only provided it as an example.  I'm having a hard time trying to revert it back to the dataframe I have in my code (df3).  For example, df3 doesn't have a column iterating the values.  But the csv does.  The only way more to replicate it properly is to recode the csv write and reimport it.

Comment: your code transforms my .csv into a by column matrix, which is throwing me off.

Comment: I was not sure in which form you want to save the output. Your original code was over-writing the previous value on each iteration, so I placed it into the matrix. You can adjust this to anything that works for you, i.e. data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks goes to Katia for the assist (specifically my x's and y's needing to be in separate dataframes)

```
combined_data_z <- df3
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173660/1731972

#file begins with numeric iterations
#ncol(combined_data_z)

dates <- combined_data_z[1]

print(dates)


#important to start at 2!, otherwise na.approx will not work!

#either copy from 2: on or copy whole and drop first column (date)
#test1 <- combined_data_z[c(2:length(parsedList)+1)]

#drop date
test1 <- combined_data_z
test1[1] <- NULL

print(test1)                  

#wtf, had to add data.frame today!
test1_z <- zoo(data.frame(test1))

date_z <- zoo(data.frame(dates))

print(test1_z)

#colnames(test1_z)

print(dates)

test1_z_approx <- na.fill(na.approx(test1_z, dates$date, rule=2, na.rm = FALSE), "extend")

print(test1_z_approx)

#new <- NULL
print(new)
new <- c(data.frame(dates),data.frame(test1_z_approx))
print(new)

write.csv(new, file = "output_test.csv")
```